Show that $\sqrt{n-2} + \sqrt{n+2}$ is irrational for all integers $n\geq3$
Show that $\sqrt{n-2} + \sqrt{n+2}$ is irrational for all integers $n\geq3$
This was asked in a test, so I'm only focused on my method that I used to answer. I'm aware there are much better methods to solve this question. Here are my workings :
Following the steps of Mathematical induction :
for $k=3$ : $\sqrt{5}+1$, which is an irrational number ...(i)
for $k+1$ : we need to prove $\sqrt{k-1} + \sqrt{k+3}$ is irrational
in $\sqrt{k-2},\sqrt{k-1},\sqrt{k},\sqrt{k+1},\sqrt{k+2},\sqrt{k+3}$ :
$\sqrt{k-2}$ and $\sqrt{k+2}$ are irrational (from i)
Now, let us define a function to see the difference between squares of integers
let f(x) = $n^2 - (n-1)^2$
f(x) = $2n-1$
f(3) = 5 {9-4}
f(x) is an increasing function, so within the domain, min(f(x)) = 5
This means the minimum gap between two integers that are squares is 5
And the gap between $\sqrt{k-1}$ and $\sqrt{k+3}$ is 4 (or 4 & 3 if we talk about true gap)
Therefore, one of them has to be irrational even if the other is rational
And since the sum of irrational and rational is irrational (in the domain of roots of positive integers),
It is proved for k+1 ...(ii)
From (i) and (ii), it is true for all $n\geq3$
I was one of the only people to attempt this question (it was a bonus question) and I am more than curious to know where I went wrong. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

The sum of two irrational numbers can still be rational. For example, $\pi + (1 - \pi) = 1$. The two radicals can be both irrational.

This problem is not suited for an induction proof.

Seems easier to square the given quantity and show that the result is irrational, so the given quantity cannot be rational.

Calling your expression $x$  I get $x^2 = 2n \pm  2 \sqrt{n^2 - 4}.$

and, for positive integer $k,$    rational roots tells us that $\sqrt k $ is irrational unless it is an integer

@WillJagy:  I’m not sure why you said $\pm$ but besides that I think your approach is good

@J.W.Tanner  I squared twice and got to $x^4 - 4nx^2 + 16$ then used the quadratic formula. Or I could have completed a square for $(x^2 - 2n)^2  = 4n^2 - 16 $

@WillJagy:  I thought you were doing what Brian Tung suggested and merely squaring $\sqrt{n-2}+\sqrt{n+2}$

If $\sqrt{n-2}+\sqrt{n+2}$ is rational, then its square $2n+2\sqrt{n^2-4}$ is rational,
so $\sqrt{n^2-4}$ is rational.  Thus $n^2-4=r^2$ with integer $r\ge0$.  Thus $(n+r)(n-r)=4$.
Thus $n+r=4$ and $n-r=1$,
which implies (adding the equations together) $2n=5$ and $n$ is not an integer,
or $n+r=n-r=2$, which means $n=2$.
This approach was suggested by Brian Tung in a comment and is similar to that of marty cohen,
just more streamlined and less general.

I thought of this, but my issue was that after squaring we end up having $2\sqrt{n^2-4}$ is rational which does not imply $\sqrt{n^2-4}$ is rational since it could be some irrational over $2$ (for example), right?

@DerekLuna:  thanks for pointing out that I mistakenly omitted the $2$; I edited to correct.  But if $2n+2\sqrt{n^2-4}=q\in\mathbb Q$, doesn't it follow that $\sqrt{n^2-4}=\dfrac q2-n\in\mathbb Q$?  In other words, if $\sqrt{n^2-4}$ is some irrational over $2$, then $2n+2\sqrt{n^2-4}$ is irrational

I see now! We really only have the rational case since the irrational case goes against the first implication.

More generally,
if
$\sqrt{n-a}+\sqrt{n+b}=m
$
with all variables being
positive integers
then
$\begin{array}\\
n-a
&=(m-\sqrt{n+b})^2\\
&=m^2-2m\sqrt{n+b}+n+b\\
\end{array}
$
so
$m^2+a+b
=2m\sqrt{n+b}
$
so
$n+b=k^2$
for some positive integer $k$.
This needs the result that
if $j$ is an integer such that
$\sqrt{j}$
is rational then
$j$ is a square.
Therefore
$m^2+a+b
=2mk
$
or
$a+b
=2mk-m^2
=m(2k-m)
$
Therefore $m | (a+b)$
and $2k-m=\dfrac{a+b}{m}$
or
$k
=\frac12(\dfrac{a+b}{m}+m)
$
and
$n
=k^2-b
$
In this case,
$a=b=2$
so
$m|4$
so
$m=1, 2, 4$.
If $m=1$ then
$\dfrac{a+b}{m}=4$
and
$k
=\frac12(\dfrac{a+b}{m}+m)
=\frac12(4+1)$
is not an integer.
If $m=2$ then
$\dfrac{a+b}{m}=2$
and
$k
=\frac12(\dfrac{a+b}{m}+m)
=\frac12(2+2)
=2$
and
$n
=k^2-b
=4-2
=2
$.
If $m=4$ then
$\dfrac{a+b}{m}=1$
and
$k
=\frac12(\dfrac{a+b}{m}+m)
=\frac12(1+4)$
is not an integer.
Therefore the only solution is
$n=2, m=2$.
Therefore there are no solutions with
$n \ge 3$.
